# Create a string of values from a do/while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to create a php string with integers separated by commas. The values for the string are coming from a do { }while loop. How would I do this?

```
//GRAB EC DATA
    $mysql_ec_data = "SELECT `ec_c_id` FROM `e_c` WHERE `ec_id` = '$e_id'";
    $query_ec_data = mysql_query($mysql_ec_data) or die(mysql_error());
    $ec_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ec_data);   

    $string = "";           
    do {

        //There will be values looping through here that I want to add to a single string.
        $string =+ $ec_data['ec_id'];               

    } while ($ec_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ec_data)); 
    //this is how the values from the while loop should look in the string at the end
    $string = 45,52,23;
```

Comment: `$string .= $ec_data['ec_id'] . ",";` ?? this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$string .= $ec_data['ec_id'] . ', ';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$string =+ $ec_data['ec_id'] . ", ";` and after the loop remove the last comma with PHP `substr` method: https://www.php.net/substr

`$string = substr($string, 0, -1);`

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your assignment-concatenation operator, in PHP it is `.=`.
A simple way to handle the comma delimiter is to first put the integers in an array 
and then "glue" them together after the loop:

```
$string = "";
$integers = array();           
do {
    $intgers[] = $ec_data['ec_id'];               

} while ($ec_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ec_data)); 

if (count($integers)) {
   $string = implode(",", $integers);
}
```